# Multi-threading and stopping a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, bigdecimal

I could really need some Help on my project. 
Task : 
The aim of the test is to create a π (Pi) calculation using various
Computation processes accelerated by multi-threading.
Use the BigDecimal class for better precision.
Use your own exception classes and pack all classes in one
neat package concept.

I tried to implement the Leibniz-method and my main issue was that i dont know how to stop a Thread from my main method while the Threads are running. My Teacher showed us and example of his mian method and you can clearly see that he is starting the method with for example 4 threads. And a few seconds later he is able to stop all of the threads. 
Here is his example of the main class:

```
        CalculatePi pi = new Leibniz();

    System.out.println("Start: " + pi.getMethodName());
    pi.startCalculation(4); //four threads

    int prec = 0;
    BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(prec < MAX_PRECISION) {
        someDelay(); //give some time to calculate
        BigDecimal newResult = pi.getValue();
        int newPrec = precicion(result, newResult);
        if(newPrec != prec) {
            System.out.println("pi (" + newPrec + "): " + newResult);
            prec = newPrec;
        }
        result = newResult;
    }
    long timeStop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    pi.stopCalculation();
    System.out.println( (timeStop - timeStart) + " ms");
    System.out.println(pi.getInternalSteps() + " calulation steps");
```

Here are my first Ideas to Implement the task (dont get confused i mainly focus on the method "startCalculation(int numThreads)" and "stopCalculation()" which are both given by an interface)

```
    // Methode soll Leibniz Verfahren mit mehreren Threads berechnen
@Override
public boolean startCalculation(int numThreads) {
    // Threads müssen in Array gespeichert werden um damit zu arbeiten
    LeibnizThread[] threadSpeicher = new LeibnizThread[numThreads];

    for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        // Neuen Thread initialisieren und im Array speichern
        threadSpeicher[i] = new LeibnizThread(numThreads, i);
        //Thread starten
        threadSpeicher[i].start();
    }
    //Warten bis alle Threads fertig sind und ihr ergebnis berechnet haben
    for(LeibnizThread w : threadSpeicher)
        try {
            w.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0.0);
    //Summe aller Threads zusammenrechnen
    for(LeibnizThread w : threadSpeicher) {
        System.out.println(w.getResult() + " Zwischenergebnis");
        sum = sum.add(w.getResult());
    }
    //Summe wird mit 4 multipliziert, um finales Ergebnis zu erhalten
    this.value = sum.multiply(new BigDecimal(4));
    System.out.println("Ergebnis: " + this.value);

    return true;
}
//Methode soll Threads aus Methode startCalculation(numThreads) stoppen, aber wie ?
@Override
public void stopCalculation() {
    flag = true;
}
```

And my Thread class looks like that:

```
public class LeibnizThread extends Thread {

private int threadRemainder;
private int numThreads;
private BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0.0);
private volatile boolean flag = false;


public LeibnizThread(int threadCount, int threadRemainder) {
    this.numThreads = threadCount;
    this.threadRemainder = threadRemainder;
}


public void run() {

    BigDecimal counter = new BigDecimal("1");

    while( !flag )  {
        if(counter.intValue() % numThreads == threadRemainder)
            if(counter.remainder(new BigDecimal("2")).equals(BigDecimal.ONE)) {
                result = result.add(BigDecimal.ONE.divide(((new BigDecimal("2").multiply(counter).subtract(BigDecimal.ONE))), 100, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            }else {
                result = result.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE.divide(((new BigDecimal("2").multiply(counter).subtract(BigDecimal.ONE))), 100, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            }
        counter = counter.add(new BigDecimal("1"));

    }
}
public BigDecimal getResult() {
    return this.result;
}

public void setFlagTrue() {
    flag = true;
}
```

}
I tried to implement a "flag" to make it stop but i dont know how to get impact on the threads which are initialized in the method "startCalculation(numThreads)" from the method "stopCalculation()" .

If anyone has an idea please let me know. Have a nice day and stay healthy :)

Comment: Hello @ProfMaschina, please consider simplifying your code examples so that it only includes [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will increase the chance, that someone answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preface; I haven't built and run your code and I haven't really looked up the Leibniz formula, so I'll just keep this answer to your threading question.

It looks like you are facing two problems here:

1. Calling `w.join()` will cause your execution to wait until the thread finishes.  Unfortunately, the thread will never finish because you will never exit `startCalculation()`.  This is called a deadlock and it's caused when one thread is forever waiting for another to finish.
2. Even if your execution got to that point, you don't know how to tell the threads to stop.

For the first issue, my advice would be to use one of Java's other helpful thread classes.  In this case, you should change LeibnizThread to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.  This will still cause a new thread to be created, but you mostly don't need to worry about the specifics.

For the second issue, you can just move the array of threads out of the method so it gets scoped at the class level.  Then, in `stopCalculation()` you can loop through the threads and tell them to stop.

I wrote up a basic framework for how you can use Runnables in cases like this.  Note that this is only one way to do it and there are tons of helpful classes in Java's concurrency library.  So look around and see all the tools that are available!

```java
package com.sandbox;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Leibniz implements CalculatePi {
    private Worker[] workers;

    @Override
    public boolean startCalculation(int numThreads) {
        // The executor service handles your thread execution for you
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

        // Start you threads and save a reference to them so you can call them later
        workers = new Worker[numThreads];
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            Worker worker = new Worker();
            workers[i] = worker;
            executorService.submit(worker); // This starts the thread.  It calls worker.run().
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stopCalculation() {
        for (Worker worker : workers) {
            worker.stopExecution();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (Worker worker : workers) {
            // Do whatever thread consolidation work you need to do here to get a single result
            result = result.max(worker.getCurrentResult());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private class Worker implements Runnable {
        private volatile boolean stopExecution = false; // "volatile" helps make sure the thread actually stops when you want it to by avoiding CPU caches
        private BigDecimal currentResult;

        Worker() {
            // Pass in whatever you need to do the work
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!stopExecution) {
                // Do all of your multi-threaded computation here, setting the currentResult as you go
                currentResult = new BigDecimal(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Example.
            }
        }

        void stopExecution() {
            this.stopExecution = true;
        }

        BigDecimal getCurrentResult() {
            return currentResult;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a little code that exercises it.  It looks a bit like your professor's code.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CalculatePi pi = new Leibniz();
        pi.startCalculation(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Current Result: " + pi.getValue());
        }

        pi.stopCalculation();

        BigDecimal finalResult = pi.getValue();
        sleep(1000);
        BigDecimal verifyFinalResult = pi.getValue();
        System.out.println("Workers actually stopped: " + finalResult.equals(verifyFinalResult));
    }
```

Results:

```
Current Result: 1586477696333
Current Result: 1586477697785
Current Result: 1586477698815
Current Result: 1586477699783
Current Result: 1586477700859
Workers actually stopped: true
```

I left a lot out because I don't want to do your homework for you, but this should help you get started.  Enjoy! :)

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer. I implemented my task with your method and it worked pretty well but the only problem is that the program keeps running after the calculation is done. I cant find the problem or maybe i am blind. It would be nice if you could help me one more time :)

Comment: @ProfMaschina It's hard to say without seeing your code.  Have you tried walking through it with a debugger?  That should be able to tell you if you're setting the `stopExecution` flag correctly.  If you are setting it correctly and the thread still isn't reading it, make sure that you have the `volatile` keyword on the boolean definition.  Without it, it's possible that your thread will never see that you set it to true.  This article has a good explanation of `volatile` (search for "Pattern #1" for your specific usecase). https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/